# How to center a Youtube video from the react-youtube

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

i am currently facing an issue
I am currently using this solution to display my youtube video, but i would like to center it on the page,
So it is responsive, i managed to make it responsive but it is stuck on the left of the screen and i am unsure of what to do. Tried playing with padding but did not seem to work.

Here is what i tried to do :

```js
import "../styles/SponsorUs.css";
import svg from "../assets/parcours.svg";
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import YouTube, { YouTubeProps } from 'react-youtube';
function Example() {
    const onPlayerReady: YouTubeProps['onReady'] = (event) => {
        // access to player in all event handlers via event.target
        event.target.pauseVideo();
    }

    const opts: YouTubeProps['opts'] = {
        height: '350',
        width: '640',
        playerVars: {
            // https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters
            autoplay: 1,
        },
    };

    return <div className='video-container'><YouTube videoId="Zu8MYX5h4x8"  opts={opts} onReady={onPlayerReady} /></div>;
}



export function SponsorUs() {

    return (
        <div className='global'>

            <div className='titleSponsor'>
                { <img className='titleSponsorImg' src={svg} alt=''/>}

                <h1>Le 4l Trophy, c’est quoi?</h1>
                <p className='titleSponsorp1'>Le 4L Trophy est un raid étudiant organisé depuis plus de 20 ans au Maroc.
                    Il s'agit d'un défi sportif et humanitaire qui réunit chaque année des milliers d'étudiants
                    venus de toute la France et d'ailleurs. Le but ? Parcourir plus de 6000 kilomètres à bord de 4L,
                    tout en acheminant des fournitures scolaires pour les enfants défavorisés du Maroc.</p>
                <h1>Notre itinéraire </h1>
                <p className='titleSponsorp2'>Notre itinéraire pour le 4L Trophy est un véritable parcours du combattant
                    !
                    Nous affronterons les routes les plus difficiles du Maroc, à travers les montagnes,
                    les déserts et les plaines arides. Nous serons confrontés à des défis physiques et mentaux,
                    mais nous sommes prêts à relever le défi !</p>
                { <img className='titleSponsorImg2' src={svg} alt=''/>}
                <h1>Trailer du 4L Trophy</h1>
                <Example />
                <h1>Vous êtes captivés par notre projet ? </h1>

            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

And here is the linked css :

```css
.video-container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%; /* Set the width of the iframe */
    height: 100%; /* Set the height of the iframe based on the aspect ratio
}
```

Thanks for your help
I think there is a slight edit to do but unsure about the where?

Comment: Why absolute position with those weird width and height?

Comment: I am unsure I was playing around with those properties. If you have any tips. Suggestions  on how to edit ?

Answer (score 0):

To center the YouTube video on the page, you can modify the CSS of the .video-container and .video-container iframe classes as follows:

```
.video-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh; /* Set the height of the container to the height of the 
viewport */
}

.video-container iframe {
  width: 80%; /* Set the width of the iframe */
  height: 45vw; /* Set the height of the iframe based on the aspect ratio 
*/
}
```

With this CSS, the .video-container is set to display: flex and justify-content: center and align-items: center, which centers the child element (the video) both horizontally and vertically within the container.

The height of the .video-container is set to 100vh to make it take up the full height of the viewport, and the width and height of the iframe are adjusted to make the video responsive.

You can adjust the width and height values of the iframe to adjust the size of the video as needed.

Comment: Hi, i am unsure about my own code, i think that it is not an iframe my video, your css almost fixes it, the only issue is a i get a vertical video but the width is not rendered properly.
Do you have any idea on how to fix?

Comment: I edited, the post, the video is now centered, but the size is not responsive, when the screen gets smaller the width and height is not adjusted, is it because some width and height are defined in the React component?